# c# linq List property and group by

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Given this sample code:

```
var item1 = ("Test1", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
var item2 = ("Test2", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });
var item3 = ("Test3", new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" });

var _list = new List<(string ID, List<string> Items)>
{
    item1,
    item2,
    item3
};

var groupby = _list.GroupBy(x => x.Items);
```

When you call `GroupBy` here, why isn't the result a single group, since the list of "Items" are all the same?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the list of `Items` are all the same"*? Each item has a different `List<string> Items` (even though they contain the same strings, they are different locations in memory).

Comment: Because each `Items` object is a different `List<>` object in memory, and the GroupBy by default looks at the object references.

Comment: Each Object in _List has a property of type new List<string>() that contains the string elements "1","2","3". Since these are all the same, why doesn't the group by clause group these together.

Answer (score 1):

Because the lists contain the same elements in the same order doesn't mean they are the same. The default definition of same for two lists is if they have the same reference, meaning if they point to the same object in the memory.

You have three different references pointing to three different objects.

If you would like to override this behaviour and re-define what "same" means, you can implement an [`IEqualityComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for `List<string>` that checks if the two lists contain same elements in same order. And supply that comparer to `GroupBy`.

Comment: That explains it. GroupBy(p => p, new SomeComparer().

Comment: A note here: The reason `List<T>` doesn't have a default equality comparer other than reference equality is that it is a mutable object.  If two instances of an object are equal at one instant, then one instance changes, it's very possible that other code would still assume they're equal.  (For example, indexing in a dictionary.)  If you aren't making further changes to your list, it's fine to make the equality comparer, but just be aware of the potential for confusing bugs here.